# i need to reset the first view with a button press

Tags: iphone, ios

on an app that i am creating, you need to slide a square through a maze and if it touches the wall, it goes to another screen telling you that you lose. However, when you hit the reset button, it goes back, and the square is in the exact same spot as where it touched the walls. Is there any way that i can press the button and have the square go back to start at the same time? Any feed back is appreciated! Thanks. (By the way, i am using Xcode.)

Here is the code for the button in the .h file:

```
- (IBAction)retry:(id)sender;
```

and here is the code for the .m:

```
- (IBAction)retry:(id)sender {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: please leave the guy some feedback on the down and close votes.

Comment: @David here you are: bad English, use of irrelevant tags, no effort made.

Answer (score 0):

Use `viewWillAppear` to reset your views

```
-(void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated { 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your initial method on buttonPressEvent.

```
- (IBAction)retry:(id)sender {

    [self viewDidLoad];

}
```